# Endpoint Error & Stuck, about to take alternate routes :(

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

After much struggle and lot of local testing created my endpoint applicaiton, but once I deploy to app engine I getting the following error.

https://ganatest6.appspot.com/_ah/api/taskandtest/v1/alerts?username=g

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }`enter code here`
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

Is endpoints not ready for Production?? If so I am stuck and need to find alternate ways.

Please help. Here is my code:

```
@Api(
  name = "taskandtest", 
  version = "v1", 
  defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE
)
public class DashboardEP {

  @ApiMethod(name = "taskandtest.alerts", 
             httpMethod = "GET", path = "alerts") 
  public String[] getAlerts(@Named("username") String username) {
    return new String[] {
      "One Alerts Feed"
    };
  }
}
```

-Gana

Comment: We need to see code to figure out what's causing the error. Can you share your Endpoint class?

Comment: @Api(
name = "taskandtest",
version = "v1",
defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE
)

public class DashboardEP {

@ApiMethod(name = "taskandtest.alerts", httpMethod = "GET", path = "alerts")

public String[] getAlerts(@Named("username") String username) {

return new String[] {"One Alerts Feed"};
}
}

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Endpoints does not support returning scalar types, such as `String[]`, which is the return type in your method.

Instead, you need to use a standard Java bean as your return type.